# Angular Page Showing Blank

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, cpanel

I have a slight issue. I am trying to access a page (made with angular) through a page (made with bootstrap) but the page made with Angular keeps showing a blank white page. I opened the developer tools and saw the following messages:"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" , "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" All the messages refer to a  CSS page. What do you think could be the issue? I tried reuploading the files before deployment but still no luck. Thanks a lot for your help!

[image]

Comment: Mate you have to give us a bit more to work with - some minimal reproducible example would be great

Comment: Can only agree to Jedo, without knowing what you do it's hard to help, but sounds a little like a wrong base-href when bulding and deploying the app.

Comment: give the picture of what you can see in the console. That will make it easier to find the exact problem..

Comment: @Jedo Sorry. I just added the image. Thank you.

Comment: @SunilLama I just added the image. Thank you.

Comment: @Fussel Thank you. Would I need to make a change to the logic of the NPM scripts? I may have missed the logic about moving the content to a specific folder.

Comment: When building your app use `ng build --base-href=/path/to/approot` alternativly you could change the path in your `index.html`, but that may cause trouble while serving dev-server. Further info: https://angular.io/guide/deployment